# How to hide or show widget by key in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Material widget like this in my StatefulWidget

```
final _key = GlobalKey();

new Material(
   key: _key,
   color: Colors.white,
   child: Text('lorem ipsum')
)
```

then I need to hide or show Material widget like this

```
new RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Click')
    color: Colors.green,
    onPressed: (){ _key.currentContext.hide; }
)
```

It's not work, how to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can make your button a child of any of this widgets which manages visibility read more on this [blog post](https://dev.to/ethiel97/handle-widgets-visibility-easily-in-flutter-5501) here is a summary:

**Visibility widget **
[visibility widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)

```
Visibility(
  visible: false,
  child: Container(),
  )
);
```

the child widget is not rendered in the subtree, and Flutter uses instead a shrinked sized box to replace it.

**Offstage widget **
[offstage widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html)

```
Offstage(
  offstage: true,
  child: //your child
  )
);
```

Offstage renders the child widget off set the screen. This means that the widget is not rendered in the subtree and so doesn't take any space.

**Opacity widget **
[opacity widget](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjIivWjpc_kAhXHbMAKHZKlDhYQtwIwBXoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flutter.dev%2Fflutter%2Fwidgets%2FOpacity-class.html&usg=AOvVaw2hzELU7OEp_ihSqVkuNZd4)

```
 Opacity(
  opacity: 0.0,
  child: Container(
      child: //child here
  )
);
```

This widget simply sets the child's opacity to zero but still renders it. So the child is hidden but takes space and you can interact with it.